# Issue with Null Printer Object when using Nexgo .aar integration in Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter

I have integrated the Nexgo .aar library into my Flutter project to enable printing functionality. The project recognizes the library correctly, but I am encountering an issue with the following line of code:

```java
printer = deviceEngine.getPrinter();
```

When running the application, the error message indicates that the "printer" object is null. I have verified that the deviceEngine is not null and the necessary dependencies are properly configured.

How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the printer object is properly initialized? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the relevant code separated into files:

**PrintNexgo.java**

```java
package com.example.printer;

import android.content.Context;

import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.APIProxy;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.DeviceEngine;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.AlignEnum;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.DotMatrixFontEnum;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.FontEntity;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.OnPrintListener;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.Printer;

public class PrintNexgo {
    private DeviceEngine deviceEngine;
    private Printer printer;
    private String sTextToPrint;

    private FontEntity fontNormal = new FontEntity(
        DotMatrixFontEnum.CH_SONG_24X24,
        DotMatrixFontEnum.ASC_SONG_12X24
    );

    public PrintNexgo(String sTextToPrint, Context context) {
        this.sTextToPrint = sTextToPrint;
        deviceEngine = APIProxy.getDeviceEngine(context);
        printer = deviceEngine.getPrinter();
        printer.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    }

    public void initPrint(Context context) {
        printer.initPrinter();
        printer.setLetterSpacing(0);
        printer.appendPrnStr(sTextToPrint, fontNormal, AlignEnum.CENTER);

        printer.startPrint(true, new OnPrintListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrintResult(int i) {
                // skip
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**PrinterPlugin.java**

```java
package com.example.printer;

import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;

import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.APIProxy;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.DeviceEngine;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.SdkResult;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.AlignEnum;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.DotMatrixFontEnum;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.FontEntity;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.OnPrintListener;
import com.nexgo.oaf.apiv3.device.printer.Printer;

public class PrinterPlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
    private Context context;
    private MethodChannel channel;
    private final String TAG = "NexGo";

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
        context = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
        channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getBinaryMessenger(), "printer");
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
        if (call.method.equals("print")) {
            PrintNexgo printer = new PrintNexgo("FROM FLUTTER", context);
            printer.initPrint(context);
        } else {
            result.notImplemented();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(null);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!